# jQuery checking img src gives undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if a specific `<img>` element has specific link. So I'm doing this:

```
if($('.watchface').find('img').attr("src") == 'http://somelink.com/that/im/trying/to/find.png')
        {
            alert("Link found");
        }
 else
 {
    alert($('.watchface').find('img').attr("src"));
 }
```

However, it doesn't work. It never finds it, and `else` simply alerts me to undefined. Any ideas why?

This is a hook over a hook over a hook in wordpress, but the usual jquery works (in case someone is wondering why I'm trying to find my own links).

Comment: whether the img element has the class watchface

Comment: It's the holder for the img element. HTML here: http://puu.sh/8rPbi.png

Comment: What does this show you? `console.log($('.watchface')); console.log($('.watchface').find('img')); console.log($('.watchface').find('img').attr('src')); `

Comment: Its working dude http://jsfiddle.net/Zm8Mx/

Comment: Do you have multiple `img` inside the `.watchface` element?  Because if that is the case, `find('img')` will return a jQuery collection.

Comment: Nope, it's a single `img` inside the `.watchface` element. @PratikJoshi yes I just noticed that, however, I still can't get it to run.

Comment: @JasonP shows me this http://puu.sh/8rPq8.png

Comment: Do you have multiple `.watchface` elements on the page?

Comment: @Steve nope, just the one

Comment: @SamFisher See the `length` property of the result? That's the number of elements found that matched the selector. Are you running this after the DOM is ready?

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a `$( document ).ready( )`? Edit: Looks like Bhargav just posted that possibility in the answer below, too. :)

Comment: Yeah, now it is. I had two wraps due to being unable to use `$` in wordpress, so I put this code in the wrong place! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the element is not yet loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(
if($('.watchface').find('img').attr("src") == 'http://somelink.com/that/im/trying/to/find.png')
        {
            alert("Link found");
        }
 else
 {
    alert($('.watchface').find('img').attr("src"));
 });
```